# Attr changing url parametr of tag a

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I want to change tag `a` attribute `href` with jquery but result was not so good than i expected.

Problem in that when i change `href` attribute with `attr`:

```
$('#doc-menu > li > a').attr('href', '/?child=False');
$('#doc-menu > li > a + ul > li > a').attr('href', '/?child=True')
```

Url cleaning fully. But before query `?child=True` i have another django url.

```
<a href="{% url 'docs:nodes_detail' node.id %}" class="parent">{{ node.name }}</a>
```

After this django url should be jquery query.

I need url like so

**35/?child=True** like so

But now i have fully cleaned url **/?child=True**

Is there anyway to find solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by appending to the existing URL instead of replacing it. you can do as follows:

```js
$("#doc-menu > li > a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + (href.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&child=False': '?child=False');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="doc-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="test1.html" >I'm without params</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="test2.html?q=ihp" >I Have extra params</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in this, i have just `appended` the query string to **url** inside the **anchor tag** using a `callback function` inside `attr`

Answer (score 0):

You can take the current url and then concatenate your string to the end.

```
var current = $("#doc-menu > li > a").attr("href");

$("#doc-menu > li > a").attr("href", current + "/?child=False");
```